# How to improve speed of programatically sending images

Tags: node.js, file, express, ejs

I am serving images via express, and substituting generic images when those images don't exist. The HTML which uses those images is generated by EJS looping through an array and creating the img src URLs.

This is a simplified version of my code:

***env***

```
    people = [
        {id: "10937290375", name: "John Smith"},
        {id: "73402394793", name: "Paul Jones"}
    ]
```

***ejs***

```
    <% for(var i=0; i < people.length; i++) { %>

      <li>
        <img src="/image/<%= people[i].id %>" />
        <span><%= people[i].name %></span>
      </li>

    <% } %>
```

***node.js***

```
    app.get('/image/:id', function(req, res) {
        var filename = `images/${req.params.id}.png`;
        res.sendFile(filename, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                filename = 'blank.png';
                res.sendFile(filename);
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem, is that it is very slow, and syncronous (I guess in part due to the way http works), but how can I speed this up?

Comment: Which part is slow? The request to your API or the rendering of your view?

Comment: The request to the API / loading of images is what's taking the time. The DOM is loaded in under a second, but the images take a further 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a third party provider as your images repo.

I recommend Cloudinary - they have node js package and very easy integration.

Comment: Looks good, but $89 for 150GB of throughput is a lot compared to my host (Digital Ocean), and there's plenty of power to serve the images quickly, if I can work out how.

Comment: You have a free plan check it out. Also, did you try working with CDN maybe?